# Removing index.php from url

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter I want to rewrite index.php from urls.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L]
```

when I use this code in my `.htaccess` `index.php` not removing.

but when I manually remove `index.php` from urls it works.

Answer (score 3):

Complete this by removing the `'index.php'` and replace with `''` in your **config/config.php**.

That should be the second key created in the file. This will change all `base_url()` and `site_url()` functions on your site.

Answer (score 0):

> when i use this code in my .htaccess index.php not removing.

Those rules only route requests to an index.php, it doesn't do anything about "removing" it. That's up to the links that you generate in your own content. If for some reason, you need to handle external links and want to redirect the client to the new URL with the index.php missing (like a Google indexing bot), then you can do this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index.php/([^\ ]+) 
RewriteRule ^index.php/ /%1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Change 
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
in config.php to
$config['index_page'] = '';

Answer (score 0):

`AllowOverride All`

Ensure allow override directive exists in apache configuration for the directory section. This enables `.htaccess` file to be read if located within the specified directory.

Eg.

```
<Directory /var/www>
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride